# I was aprroved for an ESTA but THEN denied a US visa, can I still travel?

Tags: visas, esta, us-visa-waiver-program

I applied for an ESTA and was approved, however the Question have you been arrested of an offence that caused serious damage to a person or building etc - I answered no as It was a fight I got into 18 years ago and I didn't think giving someone a split lip and black eyes was serious damage.
To be on the safe side I decided to apply for a visa and lay out all the details and be truthful. I was then denied the visa.
My question is does a visa denial cancel an ESTA? I looked at my ESTA status this morning and it still says approved, so can I travel on this? Time is of the essence as I was booked to leave in 8 days.

Comment: I assume your visa denial says you were found ineligible for a visa under 212(a). Is that right?

Comment: Well, have you been arrested or not.

Comment: Related: [ESTA is valid but the Visa was denied- can I travel to the USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46773/esta-is-valid-but-the-visa-was-denied-can-i-travel-to-the-usa?rq=1)

Comment: Previously, the ESTA question was whether you were arrested for an offence involving moral turpitude, and a simple assault did not fall under that. I believe that is still the intent of the current ESTA application even though the wording has changed.