# Arrested by police: ESTA vs US visa

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, criminal-records

For the US visa application process, they ask for arrests. I had an encounter with the police when I was in my very early teens and not sure if I was formally arrested - I certainly wasn't charged with anything.

Do I need to declare this given I have had several ESTAs in the past without any problems?

Also, if they do count it as an arrest, will this mean I won't be eligible for ESTAs in the future?

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to declare this given I have had several ESTAs in the past without any problems?

Technically you might possibly already have violated US law by not declaring it. As you can testify, however, the US won't know about your case unless you run your mouth, meaning it will be safe for you to keep visiting visa-free.

Realistically speaking, honesty is **not** always the best solution, and in this case would only serve to trap you in a web which could be a hell to get out of. [**This is a prime example of just that**](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68462/i-was-aprroved-for-an-esta-but-then-denied-a-us-visa-can-i-still-travel?noredirect=1&lq=1)

So indeed, technically you might need to get visas for the rest of your life and declare your past in the form. In practice, though, you can keep going as usual and simply make sure not to spend too much time within short periods in the US.

Comment: You don't have enough information to know whether OP has violated US law by not declaring the incident with the police. ESTA asks only about arrests "for a crime that resulted in serious damage to property, or serious harm to another person or government authority"; the DS-160 question is broader. On top of that, there's the possibility that the "encounter with the police" doesn't count as an arrest for the purpose of either question.  We don't have enough information to know that, either.

Comment: @phoog Totally true, dunno how I forgot about the first point.

Comment: The correct solution is to first check which information the UK stores on OP (FOI request, probably). If his slate is clean then there's nothing to worry. If he's actually been arrested and there's a record of it, there's a chance the Americans know about it as well.

Comment: @JonathanReez If the US does know, then they're fine with it, as again OP has been to the US visa-free and the incident was many years ago.

Comment: That's exactly it - I didn't feel in the ESTA application that my encounter fitted their description, whereas the visa application question was more broad. There was a link on here earlier, something about morality of offence, age of offence etc. which sounds like I don't need to declare for Visa (I was 14). The example @coke gave is sobering! Declaring on the visa and not previous ESTAs may be a big probity issue in their eyes. I've gone ahead and applied for a ACRO report (police report) which the visa office asks for anyway - this is more or less what JonathanReez suggested.

Comment: @bobmcpop To clarify, will your next entry be for business/pleasure or for residence? My whole point is, if it's the former, don't shoot yourself in the foot by applying for a visa.

Comment: J visa as a exchange student. For 6 months. The more I read the less I think my encounter (whether it was an arrest or not) qualifies. I think I'll not tell them. http://hub.unlock.org.uk/knowledgebase/travelling-to-the-usa-the-esta-form-and-moral-turpitude/

Comment: @bobmcpop if your encounter was an arrest then it *definitely qualifies for mention on the visa application,* even if it doesn't make you inadmissible.  If the crime was not one of "moral turpitude", or indeed if you were not convicted and do not admit committing the suspected crime, you are not inadmissible. Also if it was more then 5 years ago you qualify for the §1182(a)(2)(A)(ii)(I) exception and are not inadmissible.  However, "willfully misrepresenting a material fact" *does make you inadmissible* under §1182(a)(6)(C)(i); potentially forever, so proceed with caution.

Comment: @phoog thanks, it was over 15ys ago and I honestly can't remember. I guess I better find out - I don't know how Though except through ACRO. I assume if Nothing comes up then it wasnt an arrest. Is a "reprimand" an arrest?

Comment: @bobmcpop No it's not

Comment: The OP says he "had an encounter with the police." This is not nearly enough information to answer the question of whether or not the OP was arrested. The continuum of "encounters" runs all the way from saying "Good Morning" to the beat cop as she walks down the street, to being handcuffed, transported to jail, and locked up in a concrete-and-steel cell. The details of the OP's "encounter" matter. I'm a retired attorney who spent many years practicing criminal law.

Comment: This actually happened to me - but not in the US, it was Australia. I had a 'run-in' with police when I was a child - I ran from them, was followed, was taken to the police station. In the end I'm a 30 year old now and have no criminal record (I have checked this with a lawyer). But I went to AU on a fellowship and I declared my 'record' on my visa app. 3 yrs later, I tried to get an ETA - denied! I have to apply for AU visit visas forever. And I don't even *have* a criminal record. I just thought I did when I first applied. I was told off for being 'too honest'.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique There you go! OP, please read this if you're still following.